# trouble getting text from xpath entry in python

Tags: python, xpath, screen-scraping, lxml

I am on the website

http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/event_hr.cgi?id=bondsba01&t=b

and trying to scrape the data from the tables. When I pull the xpath from one entry, say the pitcher 
"Terry Mulholland," I retrieve this:

```
pitchers = site.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/a)
```

When I try to print `pitcher[0].text` for pitcher in printers, I get `[]` rather than the `text`,  Any idea why?

Comment: html is not xml.  Use BeautifulSoup to parse html.

Comment: FUD. lxml is fine for parsing HTML, and xpath is fine for HTML dom navigation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, last `tbody` doesn't exist in the original source. If you get that xpath via some browser, keep in mind that browsers can guess and add missing elements to make html valid.

Removing the last `tbody` resolves the problem.

```py
In : import lxml.html as html

In : site = html.parse("http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/event_hr.cgi?id=bondsba01&t=b")

In : pitchers = site.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tr[2]/td/a")

In : pitchers[0].text
Out: 'Terry Mulholland'
```

But I need to add that, the xpath expression you are using is pretty fragile. One `div` added in some convenient place and now you have a broken script. If possible, try to find better references like `id` or `class` that points to your expected location.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was very helpful. How did you know the tbody wasn't in the original source? Just look at the DOM?

Comment: @user1082471: Kind of an educated guess from experience. Then I confirmed it from the DOM. Though I was surprised to see the first `tbody` in the source :). You don't usually see `tbody` in most sources.